# Difficult limit involving integral and series

Tags: calculus, limits

I found the following problem in Hamza Alsamraee's book Advanced Calculus Explored, in the section on using series in integrals. I know the answer to the problem is $\ln{}2$.

$$ \lim_{n\to \infty}\int_0^1 \frac{x^n-x^{2n}}{1-x}dx$$

I made an attempt using a series method which required taking some steps that seemed valid to me, but that result in the wrong answer. I am curious as to what is a correct solution and what is wrong with my solution, which I will detail here.

I replaced the $\frac{1}{1-x}$ with its power series: $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_0^1 \frac{x^n-x^{2n}}{1-x}dx = \lim_{n\to \infty}\int_0^1 (x^n-x^{2n}) \sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k\ 
dx = \lim_{n\to \infty}\int_0^1 \sum_{k=0}^\infty x^{k+n}-x^{k+2n}\ 
dx $$

Since this series representation converges for all but a finite number of values within the interval (I think?), I should be able to switch the order of summation and integration by the Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem, obtaining

$$ \lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \int_0^1 x^{k+n}-x^{k+2n}\ 
dx = \lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n+k+1} - \frac{1}{2n+k+1} = \lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{n}\right) \frac{1}{1+\frac{k+1}{n}} - \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)  \frac{1}{2+
\frac{k+1}{n}}  $$

After reindexing and getting

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{n}\right) \frac{1}{1+\frac{k}{n}} - \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)  \frac{1}{2+
\frac{k}{n}}  $$

I interpreted this series as being a riemann sum (which I'm not sure is possible given the nature of the infinities in this limit) that converged to the value of this integral:

$$ \int_0^1 \frac{1}{x+1} - \frac{1}{x+2} \ dx = 2 \ln(2) - \ln(3)$$

which is wrong.

Can anyone explain to me a correct solution and where I went wrong in mine? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

If you remember the integral definition of harmonic numbers
$$H_n=\int_0^1\frac {1-x^n}{1-x}\,dx$$
$$I_n=\int_0^1 \frac{x^n-x^{2n}}{1-x}\,dx=H_{2 n}-H_n=\log (2)-\frac{1}{4 n}+\frac{1}{16 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$

I think that using $x=1-u$ and using the binomial expansion of the numerator would lead to the correst solution.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your steps, I think the following is correct for all values of $n$
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{k+n}-\frac{1}{k+2n}\right)=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k+n}=\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\frac{1}{1+\frac{k}{n}}$$
using a telescopic cancellation. So you don't have the second term in your Riemann sum (I think the limits on $k$ should be $1$ to $n$ for the Riemann sum, not $1$ to $\infty$).

So if you interpret this as a Riemann sum for $n\to\infty$, you just have
$$\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+x}dx=\log(2).$$
Not sure if the other parts of your solution are correct, but this seems to give the correct answer.

Comment: Thank you! I think that's the insight I wasn't seeing. You are right, I think interpreting the sum as a riemann sum wasn't valid with infinity as the upper bound.

Answer (score 0):

Let us write the integral under limit as $$\int_0^1 x^n\cdot\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}\,dx=\int_0^1 (x^n+x^{n+1}+\dots +x^{2n-1})\,dx$$ and the above equals $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n+k}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{1+(k/n)}$$ and this is a Riemann sum for $\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+x}\,dx $ and hence tends to the value of the integral which is $\log 2$.

There is no need to use infinite series and related complicated analysis.